# Dismissing SKScene Completely

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, skscene, dismiss

Okay so I have an app that starts off with a menu view controller that prompts user to press one of 4ish buttons which then loads a viewcontroller which then presents a scene and the user plays the game based on which button was pressed.

I am then having the user being redirected to another viewcontroller which presents another another scene, once a condition is met (they lose the game). Only problem is, the 2nd viewcontroller(and i'm assuming it's scene) is still running. I know this because I have a print statement inside of it's override function update method to see if it's still there.

In addition, I have audio playing in my old gamesene and it's still currently playing. I wouldn't EXACTLY mind that since later on i'm going to just end up passing audio data (mute all) between all 3 viewcontrollers and their presented scenes.

Only problem with what is going on right now is that when I run the app since the old viewiewcontroller an it's scene seem to still be running underneath, it keeps calling the transition which causes a weird look where when the condition meets, the transition loops endlessly to the new viewcontroller then back to the beginning of the transition then to the new viewcontroller again.

I've tried this piece of code:

```
let theVC = self.viewController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TrumpVC") as! TrumpViewController

self.viewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(theVC, animated: true)

self.viewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {});
```

But it doesn't seem to help at all :( Essentially I navigate to a new viewcontroller and dismiss the current one (this is all in my scene)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
let theVC = self.viewController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TrumpVC") as! TrumpViewController

self.viewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(theVC, animated: true)
self.viewController?.removeFromParentViewController()
self.viewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
self.view?.presentScene(nil)
```